# Safari ignores width:0 on anchor element

Tags: html, css, safari

Look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NzscL/2/) in any browser other than Safari. You should see 3 red blocks next to each other with a margin of 5 pixels to the right of each block.

If you look at [the same fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NzscL/2/) in Safari and you see much more spacing between the blocks. It seems the width of the text nodes are included (try removing `overflow: hidden`).

Strangely I couldn't find anything about this anywhere.

Does anyone know how to fix this so the blocks look the same in Safari as any other browser?

Comment: If I remove the `width` declaration, the red blocks expand but do not move. Looks like a bug in Safari.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `font-size: 0px` to get it looking the same in Safari.

Comment: @ZoltanToth can you link the fiddle? I cannot confirm.

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm on Mac. Apparently the Windows Safari isn't similar to the Mac version.. But that doesn't seem to be a problem because nobody uses Safari on Win ;-)

Comment: @ZoltanToth except to test safari-only bugs ;-)